# AWS eclipse uploading lambda function not does not upload the code

Tags: eclipse, aws-lambda

Hey I am trying to execute lambda using Eclipse using Java. I have followed [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide//lambda-tutorial.html) link but am getting the class not found exception

> Class not found: com.podcast.Hello: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.podcast.Hello
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357

When I checked the package inside AWS Lambda deployment package it just had a lib folder containing the imported libraries and nothing else. What could wrong while creating

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any Public class in your code?.. The public class name should be the name of the source file. For example : The class name is . public class Hello{} Then the source file should be as Hello.java.

Comment: Yes, I did  @ShashiBhushan

Comment: [Follow_this_link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/software-development/amazon-aws/tutorial-use-aws-lambda-s3-real-time-data-processing/) Verify the step 2.3 and see whether you have all those packages imported